# How can I send a order email to a vendor email address?

Tags: php, laravel, email

Here is my code, here is order email goes to the admin/customer but not to the vendor.

```
 //Sending Email To Buyer
    if($gs->is_smtp == 1)
    {
    $data = [
        'to' => $request->email,
        'type' => "new_order",
        'cname' => $request->name,
        'oamount' => "",
        'aname' => "",
        'aemail' => "",
        'wtitle' => "",
        'onumber' => $order->order_number,
    ];

    $mailer = new GeniusMailer();
    $mailer->sendAutoOrderMail($data,$order->id);            
    }
    else
    {
       $to = $request->email;
       $subject = "Your Order Placed!!";
       $msg = "Hello ".$request->name."!\nYou have placed a new order.\nYour order number is ".$order->order_number.".Please wait for your delivery. \nThank you.";
        $headers = "From: ".$gs->from_name."<".$gs->from_email.">";
       mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers);            
    }
    //Sending Email To Admin
    if($gs->is_smtp == 1)
    {
        $data = [
            'to' => Pagesetting::find(1)->contact_email,
            'subject' => "New Order Recieved!!",
            'body' => "Hello Admin!<br>Your store has received a new order.<br>Order Number is ".$order->order_number.".Please login to your panel to check. <br>Thank you.",
        ];

        $mailer = new GeniusMailer();
        $mailer->sendCustomMail($data);            
    }
    else
    {
       $to = Pagesetting::find(1)->contact_email;
       $subject = "New Order Recieved!!";
       $msg = "Hello Admin!\nYour store has recieved a new order.\nOrder Number is ".$order->order_number.".Please login to your panel to check. \nThank you.";
        $headers = "From: ".$gs->from_name."<".$gs->from_email.">";
       mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers);
    }

    return redirect($success_url);
```

If anyone helps, then that will be appreciated. So please guide me about that, how can I send order status email to concerned vendor.

Comment: Comment out the `order email` code and check whether the `vendor email` work or not. In my opinion it is better to use queue for sending multiple mail in a single request.

Comment: I didn't understand my dear

Comment: To check whether your vendor mail code work or not, comment out the code in first `if & else` condition using `/*  */`. Usually sending multiple emails in a single request take some time and causes errors.

Comment: It will be exactly the same as what you already have, just sending to a different address, possibly with a different `Body`, both of which are entirely up to you. This also doesn't appear to have anything to do with PHPMailer.

Comment: @UmairIlyas Really sorry, I misunderstood the admin part with vendor code.